# MacBook Pro Retina Hanging on White Boot Screen

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

My 15" MacBook Pro Retina has an issue that, on startup, the initial all-white screen shows in conjunction with the start-up chime and remains there for several seconds (up to 15-20 in extreme cases).

When I originally purchased the product, it would only take about 3-5 seconds for the Apple logo to appear and for the boot to continue.

Are there any steps I can take to cut down on the time the system spends on this all-white start-up screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Resetting my MacBook's PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14222?viewlocale=en_US) returned the boot times to normal.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons to cause this:

- Amount of storage
- The age
- torrented applications or files.

These are just the main ones, of course there is others. Try cleaning out your mac!

Note: I am not accusing you of torrenting application!